# Exporting own .jar file and importing it in another project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been looking for in a los of threads but I am not able to achieve this with the advices people give. I come from .NET and Visual Studio, so its my first time working with Eclipse and Java. I show you the steps I am following to export and import my own library, so you can tell me what I am doing wrong because I don't know what is the problem.

It is an example of a calculator, the library just have operations +, -, * and /, and I am trying to make a .jar file (.dll as i know it in .NET) to use it in other project where I just put two numbers. Steps:

1. I have created a new Java Project.
2. Inside of this Java Project I have created a package.
3. Inside of this package I have created a Class.
4. This is the code of the Class

   package LibreriaCalculadora;
   public class Operaciones {

   public int sumar(int x, int y) {
       return x + y;
   }

   public int restar(int x, int y) {
       return x - y;
   }

   public int multiplicar(int x, int y) {
       return x * y;
   }

   public int dividir(int x, int y) {
       if (y > 0)
           return x / y;
       else {
           System.out.println("El divisor no puede ser 0");
           return 0;
       }
   }
   }

Ok, now I proceed to export this Class as a .jar file following this steps:

1. Right click on project - Export.
2. Export wizard window: I choose Java - Jar File.
3. I choose the Java Project and mark the files that are in it to export it. Also I check the options below as many tutorials say. These are the pictures

[image: files checked .classpath and .project]

[image: Class file also checked]

After this step, I can see in the path I've chosen the file Operaciones.jar:
[image: Operaciones.jar file]

Ok now the Import:

1. I create a Java Project.
2. I create a package inside this Java Project.
3. I create a Class inside of this package.
4. Right click on the Java Project and choose Import.
5. In the Import wizard I choose General - Archive File.
6. In the Next step, I choose the .jar file from where it was saved before. It seems that all files I need are included. Pics below:
   [image: Importing .jar 1]

[image: Importing .jar 2]

7. Click Finish.

Now this is what I see in the Package Explorer, inside the new Java Project where I want to use my library:
[image: Folders LibreriaCalculadora and META-INF have been created]

Now the code of this Java Project where I want to use the .jar library:

```
package LibreriaCalculadoraDemo;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Operaciones.*;

public class LibreriaCalculadoraDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    int y;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Inserta el primer operando:");
    x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Inserta el segundo operando:");
    y = scanner.nextInt();


}
```

}

After all of this steps, I am not able to see what is wrong when I write `import Operaciones.*;`. I have tried also `import Operaciones.jar`, `import Operaciones.java` and `import Operaciones.class`. But nothing.. I show you a picture of what I see:
[image: Code error]

Can you please tell me if I am missing some steps or something like that? If needed, I have checked in JRE System Library folder of the project and the imported library neither is there..

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, first: please edit your question to display your code more clearly. Second: avoid posting pictures, instead, write down errors and warnings you receive. Third: I would recommend using a build tool to manage dependencies: ant, maven, or gradle should work. As for what you’re doing, I believe the problem has to do with not using the full path (package name followed by class name)

Comment: Thanks @RoyShahaf! First, I don't know why at the top it doesn't shows as code.I did the same as the code below.. I tried several times but no success. Maybe a moderator can help me. About pics, I thought is more easy to understand my steps with them because here I am doing something wrong or with the code or with the steps =(.. About build tools, I've never used any, but Im going to read about them thanks! And about the problem I've tried 'package.classname', 'package.*', 'package.classname.*', the same without package, and also 'Operaciones.jar'.. but no success, I don't understand why!! =(

Comment: Hey, regarding the code I’ve found that in eclipse what works is ctrl a (select all), tab (to indent), ctrl c (copy) then in stackoverflow you press the code button and ctrl v (paste). Regarding the pictures your reasoning is good but pictures can be very difficult to view on some screens while text is normally easier. About your problem I would suggest learning to use maven or gradle and avoid using the manual method.

Comment: @RoyShahaf finally I've found what the problem was. Until the creation of the .jar file, everything is right. The next steps are the following: 1st, I create a new Java Project. 2nd, right click in the package and create a new Class. 3rd, right click on the package and Import, and select the Archive File option. Click Next and choose the .jar file created before. This creates a package inside the project with the name given to the project where the .class of the library was created. After, I have to write the import statement inside the package of the new project. I will update the question!

Answer (score 1):

what I noticed is the class file Operaciones has a package in your file so you should try giving the name of the package with the import statement.
The syntax is 
import packagename.classname;
or import packagename.*;

Comment: Thanks @HarshKumrawat! I tried using 'LibreriaCalculadora', 'LibreriaCalculadora.Operaciones', 'LibreriaCalculadora.Operaciones.*', 'Operaciones.*', 'Operaciones.java', 'Operaciones.class', 'Operaciones.jar'... But no success. Maybe could be another problem? About the importing and exporting you think is everything right? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest you to create maven project and use its feature to create the jar file . You can follow below [this](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found what the problem was.

First, I have to create the .jar file as I mentioned at the beginning of the question.

The thing is about the Import steps. Doing the following I succeed importing the .jar:

1. I create a new Java Project called DemoCalc4. This creates in the Package Explorer the project and two elements inside of it: the JRE System Library, and the src folder. Image below:
   [image: Java project created]
2. Right click on the src folder, and create a new Package. And on the Package, right click and create a new class, where the main code is going to be written. Here is where the functions of the imported .jar will be used. In my example, I just want to write two numbers and make some arithmetical operations with them. Image below:
   [image: Main class created]
3. Right click on the src folder and click Import. Select Archive File from the wizard and select the .jar file. This will create a package inside the Java Project folder called as the .jar Java Project package. At this moment it is possible to import the class method inside the .jar file by calling the `Import` statement inside the package of the main program, create an object of the imported .jar type and use its methods. Image below:
   [image: code of the main class using the method imported from the .jar file]

Here is the final code of the main class:

```
package DemoCalc4;
import java.util.Scanner;
import LibreriaCalculadora.*;
public class DemoCalc4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        int y;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserta el primer operando:");
        x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Inserta el segundo operando:");
        y = scanner.nextInt();
        Operaciones op = new Operaciones();
        System.out.println("Suma: " + op.sumar(x, y));
        System.out.println("Resta: " + op.restar(x, y));
        System.out.println("Division: " + op.dividir(x, y));
        System.out.println("Multiplicacion: " + op.multiplicar(x, y));
    }
}
```

And this is the result after execute the main program:

```
Inserta el primer operando:
5
Inserta el segundo operando:
5
Suma: 10
Resta: 0
Division: 1
Multiplicacion: 25
```

I hope this is useful for someone. Sorry if my question was not very clear and thanks for all the comments and suggestions made, was really useful for me!